# UITableView is null

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have a view that show inside a `UITableView` with different tags that the user can choose. The point of the view is to be able to select multiple tags and also to search for a specific tag.

[This is what the view look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMDiZ.jpg)

Right now I can choose multiple choices but when I try to search between my tag I have an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code so far :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:TagCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagCell"/*, forIndexPath: indexPath*/) as TagCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = TagCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
    }

    var tag_:Tag = Tag()

    if (tableView == searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView) {
        tag_ = filteredTags_[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        tag_ = Tags_[indexPath.row]
    }

    if (tag_.isSelected_ == true) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    cell.TG_Name_.text = tag_.TG_Name_

    return cell
}
```

If I understand correctly, when I'm searching for a tag, my `UITableView` is different from my usual `TableView` and the new one is empty or something like that

When I change :

```
var cell:TagCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagCell"/*, forIndexPath: indexPath*/) as TagCell
```

to

```
var cell:TagCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagCell"/*, forIndexPath: indexPath*/) as TagCell
```

the error disappear but the checkmark disappear when I'm searching (not the same `UITableView`)

This is really frustrating.

Can somebody help me ?

EDIT :

This is my TagCell.swift
I use this kind of Cell for other TableView in other View

```
class TagCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var TG_Name_: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.cardSetup()
}

func cardSetup () {
    /*self.cardView.alpha = 1
    self.cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 1; // if you like rounded corners
    self.cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.2, 0.2); //%%% this shadow will hang slightly down and to the right
    self.cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1; //%%% I prefer thinner, subtler shadows, but you can play with this
    self.cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2; //%%% same thing with this, subtle is better for me*/
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

And this is my TagViewController

```
class TagViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

//List of Tag
var Tags_:[Tag] = [Tag]()

//search
var filteredTags_:[Tag] = [Tag]()

//?
//var selectedTags_:[Tag] = [Tag]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //self.tableView.registerClass(TagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
    self.loadTags()
}

func loadTags() {
    if (Tags_.isEmpty) {
        Tags_ = Repo_Tag().getAllTags()
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}


func tableView(tableView_: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var tag_:Tag = Tag()
    var cell:TagCell! = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TagCell
    var count:Int = 0

    if (tableView == searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView) {
        tag_ = filteredTags_[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        tag_ = Tags_[indexPath.row]
    }

    if (tag_.isSelected_ == true) {
        tag_.isSelected_ = false
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    else {
        tag_.isSelected_ = true
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

    //self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(50)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView) {
        return self.filteredTags_.count
    }
    return Tags_.count
}

func tableView(tableView_: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:TagCell! = tableView_.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TagCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        //tableView_.registerClass(TagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TagCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as TagCell
    }

    var tag_:Tag = Tag()

    if (tableView == searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView) {
        tag_ = filteredTags_[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        tag_ = Tags_[indexPath.row]
    }

    if (tag_.isSelected_ == true) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    cell.TG_Name_.text = tag_.TG_Name_

    return cell!
}

//Functions to take care of the search
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    self.filteredTags_ = self.Tags_.filter({( tag: Tag) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = tag.TG_Name_.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, willHideSearchResultsTableView tableView: UITableView) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

When i comment

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
```

I have no errors
When i uncomment in my viewDidLoad, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Have you registered a cell, what is it?

Comment: why u have put indexPath in comment block(/* */)  I don't understand tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TagCell"/*, forIndexPath: indexPath*/) as TagCell

Comment: @Shashi3456643 because i tried different things before posting

Comment: Can you uncomment and then tell me the error which u r getting. Also share code with us which u r trying to reload tableview after search

Comment: I think you haven't put TagCell value in Reusable View of UITableViewCell identifier. if it is not there go then and put cell identifier value to TagCell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't registered the correct cell class / NIB, though it seems you have registered some cell as you only get 1 crash.

So, in one instance you get a crash because you are asking for a cell that doesn't exist and trying to set it into a mandatory variable.

In the other case you get a cell, but it isn't a configured `TagCell`.

I'm guessing what you might have done is register the cell class as `TagCell`, but you should really have registered an XIB or named the cell in a storyboard prototype. It's hard to tell exactly what you need but you should read the docs for the dequeue methods you're using and how to register cells.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm trying to register my cell and now it fail everytime
I added 'self.tableView!.registerClass(TagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")' in my viewDidLoad() and it doesn't work, i don't know where i failed

Comment: So i added self.tableView!.registerClass(TagCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell") to my viewDidLoad and
if (cell == nil) {
            tableView_.registerClass(TagCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
            cell = TagCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
        } to my cellForRowAtIndexPath function

and when i load the view it crash on the first line (dequeue...) with :
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: If you register a cell you always dequeue, never create explicitly. So you shouldn't have a check if cell is nil because the dequeue promises it won't be. Indeed you set the bar as mandatory so it will crash if it fails before it gets to your check. And a crash means the cell wasn't registered correctly. You should update the question with the latest code that you're actually testing and the associated error (code isn't readable in comments).